# Quitar submenú usuarios en dashboard de sonata admin predeterminado en FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony2, fos-user-bundle

Estoy intentado quitar el submenú usuarios que queda en el panel de *Sonata Project* que viene por defecto al instalar *FOSUserBundle*, pero no lo he conseguido. ¿En qué parte está esa configuración para quitar ese *dropdown* de usuarios? Si se fijan en el pantallazo tengo dos submenús usuarios. Uno que es heredado de Fosuser y creado por mí, y el otro que viene por defecto. ¿Cómo hago para quitar ese submenú? Anexo pantallazo para que sea más entendible.

[image: Pantallazo del submenú usuarios en Sonata Project.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende de como estes definiendo los admin de tu aplicacion (en teoria deberias definir los servicios de admin en un archivo tipo sonata.yml en el bundle de Application). Pero en general esto esta en el archivo de services.yml en el que tengas definido el servicio de admin de usuario, en concreto en los **TAGS**

Por ej, si yo tengo:

```
app.admin.news:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\NewsAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\News, SonataAdminBundle:CRUD]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: admin, label: News }
```

La etiqueta TAGS indica que es un servicio sonata (name) que esta basado en orm, y el **group** se llama admin, con un elemento label llamado **News**

En tu caso, seguramente tengas algo como:

```
app.admin.user:
    class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
    arguments: [~, Application\Sonata\UserBUndle, SonataUserBundle:CRUD]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: user, label: User }
```

Esto es una aproximación. La idea es que busques la definición en tu app y cambies el GROUP por el agrupador que te interese.

Si lo que quieres, es que no aparezca el admin, entonces buscalo y añade **show_in_dashboard: false** :

```
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: user, label: User, show_in_dashboard: false }
```

Con esto ultimo ese admin sigue definido pero no aparecerá en el panel.

Comment: Muchas gracias, encontré el servicio en Vendor/Sonata-project/UserBundle/Resources/Config/admin_orm.xml ahi encontre los dos servicios y les puse la opción show_in_dashboard: false, y funcionó.

Comment: recuerda que en symfony2 y 3 no hay que escribir en las carpetas de Vendor, ya que cuando vuelvas a ejecutar el composer (por ej, para añadir otro vendor) te va a actualizar ese cambio y volveras a ver el menu. Lo mejor es que sobreescribas el bundle (sonata tiene el comando easy-extends ) y ahi es donde harias los cambios.

Comment: amigo, entonces como debe hacer para no sobreescribir en vendor?... sé que debo crear ese archivo en mi propio Bundle, pero lo intente copiando admin_orm.xml a Resources/Config de mi bundle y no funcionó, entonces como debo hacerlo, me puedes guiar porfavor!... muchas gracias

Comment: Revisa en la documentación de sonata el easy-extends bundle. Es la forma de sobreescribir vendidos de sonata